# Replying to private message on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

First my research only brings up cases of replying to messages sent to a page? what about direct messages? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A message between User and Page would also be a "Direct Message", but if you mean "User to User" messages: There is no API for it, you can only reply to messages sent to a Page.

Comment: so that's that then. I post stuff on marketplace and people ask same thing over and over again. is it available?.. what if i built a chrome extension that just goes through messenger and reply to all messages. is there messenger undocumented api that you can ping for new messages .. thanks

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, there is no way.

Comment: how does app trillian works then, they have messenger integration

Comment: probably with some special agreement with facebook.